# PowerShell Script to Delete files from all SubFolders which are older than 30 days

Tags: powershell

I want to delete all types of Files from below folder structure which is older than 30 Days. So I used below PowerShell Script. But it is not deleting any file.

PowerShell Script:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  "C:\Users\VJ\Documents\MainDir" –Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | Remove-Item
```

Folder Structure:

```
  MainDir
     |
  SubDir1 -> Folder1 -> Folder2 -> Zip/CSV files 
  SubDir2 -> Folder1->.txt files
               |
              Folder2 -> .txt files
```

End Result should be all types of Files deleted from all folders - subfolders of MainDir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are confusing the properties [CreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime) and [LastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime).

If you've just copied (old) files to one of the directories in the structure, the `CreationTime` is the date and time the file was copied there, which can be today. The `LastWriteTime` property however shows the date and time the file was last written to.

Try:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\VJ\Documents\MainDir" -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | 
    Remove-Item -Force
```

If you're on PowerShell version less than 3.0, use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\VJ\Documents\MainDir" -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | 
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Also, check and retype your dashes, because they may LOOK like normal hyphens, in fact they are [EN Dashes](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp) (Hex value 2013; Decimal 8211)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks @Theo it worked. But how can I add same command for another folder in a single PowerShell script? So single script for multiple folders.

Comment: @VikasJ The `-Path` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` can take an array of paths. So you can do `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\VJ\Documents\MainDir", "C:\Users\VJ\Documents\SecondaryDir" -Recurse` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\VJ\Documents\MainDir" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | Remove-Item -Force`